# If ...Checked

Tags: c#, checkbox, if

Вообщем, опять глупый вопрос. На форме имеется несколько чекбоксов и радиобутонов(radioButton1_CheckedChanged). Нужно сделать так, чтобы после того, как мы жмакнули на него и вышло сообщение, оно не появлялось после снятия чека. Надеюсь, что ясно изъяснил. Спасибо.

Comment: Необходимо ввести логическую переменную флага. Изначально присваиваете ему false. После нажатия на кнопку, флаг становится true, после повторного нажатия, флаг становится false.  
/*Действие, выполняемое при нажатии на кнопку*/  
if(flag==false) flag=true; else flag=false;  
В это же время, флаг управляет отображением окна.   
/*Условие для отображения окна*/  
if(flag){/*отображаем окно*/}

Answer (score 1):

Условие при котором должно выводиться сообщение должно выглядеть так - if(radioButton1.checked==true)... Кажется так должно быть

Comment: Когда я отмечаю бокс - сообщение есть. Теперь нужно сделать наоборот: снимаешь чек - сообщение не появляется.

Comment: if(radioButton1.checked==true & radioButton2.checked==false) такое условие попробуй

Comment: @handbat0, ваше условие равносильно следующему: `if (radioButton1.Сhecked & !radioButton2.Сhecked)`. Удобнее ведь читать :)